# Function to sum a multi digit number until a single digit is returned

Tags: python

I need help with with writing a python script to sum a multi digit number until a single digit is left. So any number equal to 10 or greater.

The program will accept 10 for instance and return 1.

Numbers 1 - 9 should return as an error and 0 should return as 0. Entries that are not int should return an error too.

I have written multiple versions of this but I can not seem to get it to work the way I want it to.

Here is some code I am working with:

```
  def SumDig(n):
    n = []
   if(not isinstance(n, int)) or (n <= 9) or (n >= 1):
      return ("Error")
   elif(n >= 10):
      return (n - 1) % 9 + 1;
   return SumDig(n)
```

Comment: If you were given an assignment, you should probably just share the text of the assignment because the requirement you've provided above is unclear. I think we can guess what you need to do, but a more accurate statement would help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need it to be recursive:

```
def sumDigits(N):
    if N is 0: return 0
    if not isinstance(N,int) or N < 10: return "error"
    return (N-1)%9+1
```

Answer (score 0):

We can get the single digit of sum multiple ways,

```
#simplest while loop method
n = int(input('Enter the digits = '))
sum = 0

while(n>0 or sum>9):
    if(n==0):
        n = sum 
        sum = 0

    sum += n%10
    n = int(n/10)

print(sum)

       #or

#Recursion method
def sums(n):
    sum = 0
    while (n>0):
        x = n% 10
        sum += x
        n = int(n/10)
    if(sum>9):
        n = sum
        return sums(n)
    else:
        return sum
n = int(input('Enter the digits = '))
print('The single digit sum of digits = ',sums(n))
```